# Angular JS + VF component binding

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, angularjs, angular

I have the following scenario:

VF page:

```
    <div ng-controller="listingGeneratorCtrl">
        <div>
            <div id="rightColumn">
                <div ng-repeat="section in container.Sections">
                    <div ng-model="section">
                        <c:myComponent />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mymodule = angular.module("myapp", ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);

        mymodule.controller('myController', 
            function($scope) {

                $scope.container = {};

                $scope.loadContainer = function(id) {
                    myServerController.LoadContainer(id,
                        function(result, event){
                            console.log(result);

                            if(event.status) {
                                $scope.container = result;
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log(event);
                            }
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }
                    );
                };

                angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                    $scope.LoadContainer('{! $CurrentPage.parameters.id }');
                });

                window.__scope = $scope;
            })
```

VF component "myComponent":

```
<apex:component>
    <div ng-repeat="element in section.elements">
        <div ng-bind="element.name"></div>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

The problem:
The data is transmitted correctly from server to client side, however the component is not receiving the data, apparently, because it is rendered empty.

The question:
Is there any specific way to bind data to the component? I mean, if component "mycomponent" is under a 'div' with ng-model="section", it must get the value of 'section' variable as the bound data, right? 
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using your browser's "View Source" or "Inspect" feature to review the overall HTML generated might reveal something - its that HTML that Angular is working against.